# Error dialog "The file 'exclude' doesn't exist" when creating a new git-backed XCode project

Tags: xcode, git, xcode6

When creating a new project in XCode 6, if I check the "Source Control: Create Git repository on My Mac" button in the Save sheet, the project is successfully created, but I get an error dialog saying

**The file "exclude" doesn't exist**

Also, a git repo is initialized for that project, but no files are added to it.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

(Seen on Yosemite, in several versions of XCode 6, including both the 6.0.x and 6.1.x series.)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050229/xcode-6-0-1-error-when-creating-project-the-file-exclude-doesnt-exist

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe in Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, I saw that other post, but (a) I wanted to add in more information than the OP had, and (b) there were no answers on that one.